# Vue.js async function passing variable as undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I'm encountering an issue in my Vue.js application where an async function is passing a variable as `undefined` even though it's correctly defined before the function call.

I have an async function `FETCH_DATA` in my Vue.js application defined as follows:

```js
async [FETCH_DATA](
  {
    rootGetters,
  },
  { dataList, retries = 3 },
) {
  // Code to fetch data
},
```

This function is called from another method handleSubmission, where the itemList variable is correctly defined and logged before the call to FETCH_DATA. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
async handleSubmission(successResponse) {
  const { itemId } = successResponse;
  if (successResponse.isPromotional) {
    const itemList = [itemId];
    console.log('Logged itemList:', itemList);
    const response = await this.fetchData(itemList);
    // Further code execution
  }
},
```

However, when the itemList variable is passed to FETCH_DATA, it becomes undefined. Here's the output from the console logs:

```
Logged itemList: [123456]
Received itemList in FETCH_DATA: undefined
```

I've tried checking the scope, ensuring proper variable passing, and debugging with console.log statements, but I can't seem to figure out why itemList is becoming undefined in the FETCH_DATA function.

Comment: "rootGetters" suggests that you may be using vuex, but this is not specified. It's unclear what's the relation between FETCH_DATA and fetchData. If fetchData is mapped with vuex mapActions, this should be mentioned. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the object that wraps around the `itemList`.

```js
await this.fetchData({ dataList: itemList });
```